# Is data validation required in getter property even after the same data was checked in the setter?

Tags: c#, validation, properties, attributes, encapsulation

I want to validate if the name value entered by the user does not include any numbers and is within the range [3-8] characters.
I applied the test in the setter property as it is where the value will be assigned to the private attribute name. The condition is if the name is less than 3 or greater than 8 or it contains any numbers, the set value for the attribute -name- will be "Unnamed". However, after creating an instance of the class and passing the name argument ("Gigi5") to the constructor, instead of returning "Unnamed" (since the name contains a number) it returned "Gigi5" which is not what it's supposed to happen based on the condition.
The confusing thing is, when I put the conditional station in the getter property, only then then I get the correct output, which doesn't make sense because it is in the setter where the data is assigned to the attribute and the getter will only retrieve the value that was sat by the setter. right?

Now I tried one thing, The constructor takes arguments which are assigned to the private attributes directly. I tried replacing the [this.name = ] by the property name "Name =" and only then the code worked without having to use the same conditional statement in the getter property too.

One thing is that the constructor gets the arguments and assigns them the private attributes directly, but those attributes will not get those values unless the setter property processes the values first? isn't that how it works?

```
public class Cat
{
    private string name ="Unnamed";
    private string color = "Gray";

    public string Name
    {
        get 
        {
            return name;
            //if ((name.Length <= 8 && name.Length>=3) && Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[a-zA-Z]$"))
            //{
            //    return name;
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    return "Unnamed";
            //}
        }
        set
        {
            if ((name.Length <= 8 && name.Length>=3) && Regex.IsMatch(name, @"^[a-zA-Z]$"))
            {
                name = value;
            }
            else
            {
                name = "Unamed";
            }
        }
    }

    public string Color
    {
        get => color;
        set => color=value;
    }

    public Cat(string name, string color)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }
    //public Cat(string name, string color)
    //{
    //    Name = name;
    //    Color = color;
    //}
}
```

//The following example is what I tried to test if the validation on the setter is working.
Cat cat1 = new Cat("Gigi5", "orange");
Console.WriteLine($"{cat1.Name}'s color is {cat1.Color}");

Comment: Because the constructor code doesn't use the property but set directly the internal field name. The validation code runs only when you set the property. Also you need to check for _value_ inside the set code. _value_ represents the data passed to the set code. You are checking if _name_ respects the conditions now

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried checking if the _value_ itself respects the conditions and yet got the same results. I just don't understand why the condition in the setter doesn't execute as I pass the arguments to the attributes. well the attributes are private and the only way to have values assigned to them is through the property. otherwise the private keyword and the property data validation is useless. Does this mean if I have properties in my classes, those properties are supposed to be in the constructor's body instead of the attributes themselves?

Comment: No, when you assign a value to the _name_ field you are not using the property and thus you are not running the validation code. The constructor code bypass the property and assigns directly to the field. If you want to assign by property then you should write _this.Name = valuefornameinconstructor_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to mention:

1. For your purposes your regex string wasn't 100% correct. the [a-zA-Z] string only applies to 1 character so you need to denote how many this applies to after the character itself. In this case {3,8} is a quantifier allowing for between 3 and 8 characters of the type [a-zA-Z]. I recommend checking your regex using an online regex tester as it can save a lot of time.
2. In your Cat constructor method you were setting your private variable "name", whereas your get/set methods apply to the variable "Name".
3. When you are comparing your input variable in your set method, you are comparing to the private variable "name", however, the value that gets passed to the "set" method is aptly named as "value" before you do anything to it within the method. Hence you need to check the length of "value", not "name" within the set method:
   `if ((value.Length <= 8 && value.Length >= 3) && Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[a-zA-Z]{3,8}$"))`

   ```
   public class Cat
   {
       private string name = "Unnamed";
       private string color = "Gray";

       public string Name
       {
           get
           {
               return name;
           }
           set
           {
               if ((value.Length <= 8 && value.Length >= 3) && Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[a-zA-Z]{3,8}$"))
               {
                   name = value;
               }
               else
               {
                   name = "Unnamed";
               }
       }
   }

   public string Color
   {
       get => color;
       set => color = value;
   }

   public Cat(string name, string color)
   {
       this.Name = name;
       this.Color = color;
   }

   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       Cat cat1 = new Cat("Gigi5", "orange"); 
       Console.WriteLine($"{cat1.Name}'s color is {cat1.Color}");

   }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a value to an internal field inside its class you are not using the related property's code. You are just setting a variable with a value. So if you want to use that validation code you need to use the property in some way.

The first fix is in the constructor. You should write the assignments using the properties. Note the capital letter.

```
public Cat(string name, string color)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Color = color;
}
```

but then there are another problem. In the validation code you have used the check using again the internal field but this makes no sense. The internal field has still the previous value, not the one that you are trying to assign. So the check should be done on the *value* assigned

```
if ((value.Length <= 8 && value.Length >= 3) && ...
```

Finally the last error is in the Regex. You are checking only on the first char of the *value* not on the whole string. You should change the regex check to (Note the * before the end of line marker)

```
&& Regex.IsMatch(value, @"^[a-zA-Z]*$"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Sorry can't upvote you. don't have enough reputation to do that.